# How to test a button its text changes depending on useState()

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

This is my jsx and when click the button the state changes and the button text changes too
`

```
const [copied, setCopied] = useState(false);

<button
          className={`btn ${copied ? 'copy copied' : 'copy'}`}
          onClick={() => {
            setCopied(true);
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(shortedLink);
          }}
        >
          {copied ? 'copied!' : 'copy'}
        </button>
```

`
How to test this conditional text with Jest & RTL

I'm new to unit testing and, I've tried those two solutions but the two failed
-- the first said -- value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement. Received has value: null

-- the second said -- Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
`

```
it('should change the text of the button when clicked', async () => {
    user.setup();
    render(<ShortedLink />);
    const copyBtn = screen.getByRole('button', {
      name: 'copy'
    });
    const copiedBtn = screen.queryByRole('button', {
      name: 'copied!'
    });
    expect(copyBtn).toBeInTheDocument('copy');
    expect(copiedBtn).toBe(null);
    await user.click(copyBtn);
    expect(copiedBtn).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

`and`

```
it('should change the text of the button when clicked', async () => {
    user.setup();
    render(<ShortedLink />);
    const copyBtn = screen.getByRole('button', {
      name: 'copy'
    });
    expect(copyBtn).toHaveTextContent('copy');
    await user.click(copyBtn);
    expect(copyBtn).toHaveTextContent('copied!'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps:

- get button with `copy` text and ensure it is there in the document
- click that button => the text should change so...
- get the button with `copied!` text and ensure it is in the document

```js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

import ShortedLink from "../ShortedLink";

describe('it should work', () => {
  it('should work', async () => {
    render(<ShortedLink />);

    const copyButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'copy' });
    expect(copyButton).toBeInTheDocument();

    await userEvent.click(copyButton);

    const copiedButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'copied!' });
    expect(copiedButton).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```